# When should I use connection pooling with MySQL in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, connection-pooling

Working with the **Node-MySql** module:

From my understanding multithreaded programs benefit more from pooling connections than singlethreaded ones. Is this true?

And if this logic proves true, what scenario is connection pooling **beneficial** in a Node.JS application?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Whether single or multithreaded, pooling can still be beneficial in [allowing open connections to be reused](https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql#pooling-connections) rather than being closed only to open another immediately after:

> When you are done with a connection, just call `connection.release()` and **the connection will return to the pool, ready to be used again by someone else.**

The added benefit with multithreading is that the pool can also manage multiple, concurrent connections:

> Connections are lazily created by the pool. If you configure the pool to allow up to 100 connections, but only ever use 5 simultaneously, only 5 connections will be made.

Though, to be clear, Node is multithreaded. It just uses a different model than seems to be typical -- 1 "*application*" thread which executes JavaScript and multiple "*worker*" threads handling the brunt of asynchronous I/O.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying whether it's singlethreaded or not. Just took a look at Cluster- that's the game changer. Just one small correction- connection.end has been changed to connection.release as of 20 hours ago. https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql/commit/d5753f83ab139e5ebb04adf22497bfab94f4c985