# Nodejs best way to implement database connection (mysql)

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I'm working on a nodejs server.

I see there are many ways to implement mysql connection as:

- 1 connection and never it never end (handle error and re connect again)
- A connection pool (How can i know my mysql server allow how many connections at a time)
- Init a new connection when we need it (a http resquest...) then end it when done.

My question is: What is the best way to do implement mysql on my server.
Or each of them has cons or pros -> show me.

Answer (score 2):

I've meddled with both not using pools and using pools and after doing so I'd recommend that you set up pooling. Persistent connections will lead to problems if you're dealing with asynchronous code which is what Node is great for. If you end up trying to do 2 calls on the same persistent MySQL handler at the same time, it won't like it. Go for pooling.

Not sure why you'd ever want to connect to SQL over HTTP for Node.

> How can i know my mysql server allow how many connections at a time

Check the max_connections setting in your MySQL config (my.cnf).

Comment: You can also run this query (from the MySQL shell for example): `show variables like "max_connections";`

Answer (score 1):

Here is a [related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17611284/2137601) that can help you understand the pros of pooling connections.

You can also take the example of Sequelize, an ORM for Node that supports MySQL. As you can see from [the documentation](http://sequelizejs.com/documentation#usage-options), you can choose to use either one connection per request, or a pool of connections with an idle timeout (ie. you close the connection once it has been idle for some time).